# Does Gatling provide a way to compare previously run tests

Tags: gatling

I've been running Gatling tests and I have a whole bunch of reports in the results folder.
For example I have a report for 200 requests per second and one for 400 requests per second.

Is there anyway to compare the reports against each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only the [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gatling+Plugin) for now.

That's something we plan on providing as a commercial offer.

Comment: any update on this? comparison of the previous and current report is a mandatory check in the continuous delivery pipeline. it would be great if gatling gives this feature.

Comment: Answer is still the same: either Jenkins plugin or upcoming commercial product.

Answer (score 2):

Gatling itself provides enterprise version called [Gatling Frontline](https://gatling.io/gatling-frontline/), which does support trends and history runs.

Another possibility is to use your `simulation.log` and process them using [nuxeo gatling-report](https://github.com/nuxeo/gatling-report) utility like this:

```
# check https://maven-eu.nuxeo.org/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~gatling-report for latest version, or build from source
wget 'https://maven-eu.nuxeo.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/public-releases/content/org/nuxeo/tools/gatling-report/4.0/gatling-report-4.0-capsule-fat.jar'
# do not create outputReportDirectory !
java -jar gatling-report-4.0-capsule-fat.jar results/complexscenario-20200618125705159/simulation.log results/complexscenario-20200617130307094/simulation.log -o outputReportDirectory
```

If you intend to generate trends during maven build, you can have a look at [DennisRippinger gatling-reporter maven plugin](https://github.com/DennisRippinger/gatling-reporter), which encpsulates previously mentioned project.